# What is needed for elementaryos.stackexchange to be out of private beta stage?

Tags: discussion

When would elementaryos.stackexchange be fully open?

[image]

Comment: It's up and a public beta now ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 2 weeks is approximately the duration of the private beta phase. After that, we're into public beta which anybody can join (not only those who committed during the proposal). Public Beta does not have a fixed duration; it lasts as long as it takes for the site to be approved to become a legitimate member of the StackExchange network.

Comment: Adding "What questions are off-topic" on this stack would help focus how this will be any different from Unix & Linux and AskUbuntu (Although since its not an official derivative of Ubuntu, any questions posed there are immediately and irrevocably closed as off-topic).

Comment: Well actually, there's a [huge number](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:area51.stackexchange.com+%22didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta%22+-site:discuss.area51.stackexchange.com&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=P1i1VanJIcWMsAGvrr3IAw) of beta sites that got closed because of the inactivity.