# What is needed for this site to go out out of (public) beta?

Tags: discussion

["Public Beta does not have a fixed duration"](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/a/58/170)

But what are the specific requirements for this site to be out of "beta" stage?

A number of users maybe?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/266359 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239464/266359

Answer (score 5):

You can view these requirements on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82707/elementary-os).

While these won't definitely get you out of beta, they are things that are looked for. We are fine on the number of users, although a few more over 200 rep is required. We need a few more questions a day and a *lot* more answers.

Comment: Over a year past, and a lot of progress has been made, but the flow of low quality questions, low rep users and a lack of reviewers has meant we are still not there. We are only a few users away from having 150 users with 200+ rep though, so perhaps reviewing some questions and answers and upvoting good ones is an option to help us with all remaining problems.